# Python-Count how many times pair of names appears in 5 pdf files?

Tags: python, pdf, count

I have 5 pdf files.
Also, I have a list of 700 authors. I need to check all the possible pairs of authors that have worked together and how many times in this files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It could be nontrivial if the same author is referred to differently in different documents. For example, one bibliography style might use full names and another initials for the first name.

Comment: The authors referred similarly in all of the files. Just using First name and Last name.